# How to make this ansible chkconfig task idempotent ?

Tags: centos, ansible

I have a ansible task like this in my playbook to be run against a centos server:

```
   - name: Enable services for automatic start
     action: command /sbin/chkconfig {{ item }} on
     with_items:
       - nginx
       - postgresql
```

This task changes every time I run it. How do I make this task pass the idempotency test ?

Comment: Use `changed_when` parameter: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result

Comment: The best option is to use the `enabled=yes` with service module

Comment: @arbabnazar you should post that as an answer

Comment: I was going to say that this is the kind of thing that `ansible-lint` would help with, except that now I notice that `chkconfig` is not here: https://github.com/willthames/ansible-lint/blob/master/lib/ansiblelint/rules/CommandsInsteadOfModulesRule.py

Comment: If you ever need 'chkconfig reset', then the service module cannot help you. In that rare case you'll use changed_when.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best option is to use the `enabled=true` with service module:

```
- name: Enable services for automatic start
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    enabled: true
  loop:
    - nginx
    - postgresql
```

Hope that help you.